# Coulombic potential energy of Hydrogen $1s$ orbital?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen, virial-theorem

Given that $\langle \psi_{1s}|\hat H|\psi_{1s}\rangle=\langle \psi_{1s}|\hat K+\hat V|\psi_{1s}\rangle=-13.6$eV, does any one know the exact value of $\langle \psi_{1s}|\hat V|\psi_{1s}\rangle$? I tried to find it online but didn't get it... Thanks!

Comment: I get -27.2567eV by numerical integration but I'm not sure if it's correct...

Comment: Anyone who could point to a reference for such numerical values will be really helpful!

Comment: Do you know the UP argument resulting in this factor of 2?

Comment: @CosmasZachos No...but I’d really love to learn about it if you can explain that a little bit.

Comment: $\langle \hat K \rangle=\frac{me^4}{32\pi^2\epsilon_0^2\hbar^2}\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\langle \hat V \rangle=-\frac{me^4}{16\pi^2\epsilon_0^2\hbar^2}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: That’s for Schrodinger-equation wavefunctions, not Dirac-equation wavefunctions.

Comment: @Macrophage  look for *virial theorem*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Schrodinger-equation wavefunctions for hydrogen, the expectation values of the kinetic energy and the (electrostatic) potential energy are

$$\langle \hat K \rangle=\frac{\mu e^4}{32\pi^2\epsilon_0^2\hbar^2}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\alpha^2}{2n^2}\mu c^2$$

and

$$\langle \hat V \rangle=-\frac{\mu e^4}{16\pi^2\epsilon_0^2\hbar^2}\frac{1}{n^2}=-\frac{\alpha^2}{n^2}\mu c^2.$$

Here $\mu=\frac{m_em_p}{m_e+m_p}$ is the reduced mass of the electron and proton, $e$ is their charge, $\epsilon_0$ is the electric constant, $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck constant, $c$ is the speed of light, $\alpha=\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar c}$ is the dimensionless fine-structure constant, and $n$ is the principal quantum number (1 for the 1s state).

Numerical values for the relevant constants are $\mu c^2=510721$ eV, $\alpha=0.00729735$, and $\alpha^2\mu c^2=27.1966$ eV.

The expectation value of the kinetic energy is of course positive. The expectation value of the potential energy is negative because the electrostatic force between the proton and the electron is attractive.

The factor of two between their magnitudes is a consequence of the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem#In_quantum_mechanics). The same ratio holds in the Bohr model of hydrogen, and in the Solar System! It comes from the forces being inverse square forces.

The expectation value of the total energy is negative, expressing the fact that the electron is bound to the proton; energy must be added to a hydrogen atom to ionize it.

Note that the three expectation values depend only on one of the three quantum numbers, namely the principal or radial quantum number $n$. They are independent of the angular quantum numbers $l$ and $m$. This can be understood as a consequence of the hydrogenic Schrodinger equation having a non-obvious $SO(4)$ symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try solving the time derivative term, times "iℏ". And then solve for the kinetic energy term. In which:

$$Ѱ=e^{i}(kx-wt)$$
And then minus the kinetic energy term from the time derivative term (which is multiplied by iℏ). And then substitute the values of "k", and "w", for a 1s Hydrogen orbital.

Comment: Sorry for the grammatical mistakes, the first line is suppose to be "I guess you can try solving the time derivative term, times "iℏ".

Comment: Hi Matrix001, note that you can edit your posts with the “edit” button on the bottom left of the post (may be different on mobile app). Additionally, we have MathJax enabled in this site so that you can use LaTeX-like commands to display mathematical symbols; search ‘notation’ in [help] for more details